How to start, stop and restart a set of systemd service units as a group?
I have created a systemd "target" which allows starting of a group of services together. However, it does not work when trying to stop the group of services.
my_target.target:
[Unit]
Description=my description
Wants=\
    service1.service \
    service2.service
After=\
    service1.service \
    service2.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

service1.service:
[Unit]
Description=my description
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=60
User=theuser
Group=thegroup
EnvironmentFile=/etc/example_env
WorkingDirectory=/var/log/example
StandardOutput=append:/var/log/example/service1.log
StandardError=append:/var/log/example/service1.error.log
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/example/.venv/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/example/service1.py
ExecStop=/bin/kill -TERM $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=my_target.target

service2.service:
(The same as above, but service1->service2)
Installation:
Both the service files and the target file are installed in /etc/systemd/system/.
I created a directory /etc/systemd/system/my_target.wants. Both of the service files have symbolic links in this .wants directory.
I am not totally sure if this is the correct way to setup a "target" which controls a group of services (systemd units) as a group.
Edit
For anyone reading this in future, my suggestion would be to use Docker instead of systemd to manage processes.
Docker has a number of advantages:

It is cross platform, meaning that it is easy to migrate your application stack from one platform to another (eg: Linux to Windows Server)
It is easier to deploy, because applications are containerized. This means that it is easy to migrate your application(s) from one host to another (eg from one virtual machine to another, from one physical host to another, etc)
It is designed to run groups of containers together as a group. On the other hand, it seems to be more difficult to find information about how to do this with systemd, and I am not convinced this is really an intended use case
There are other advantages associated with the fact that applications are containerized, rather than running natively. I have found that application stability is far less important, because a misbehaving application cannot crash the whole system. Sometimes there may be bugs in libraries which you do not have control over, therefore you cannot diagnose or fix those bugs. If a containerized application crashes, it is highly unlikely to also crash the host, and it will simply be restarted (if set to automatically restart).

In my experience, I have found it generally easier to use Docker for process management in comparison to systemd. There are some things which are not quite as straight forward - for example, log files will be written inside the container file system which makes them slightly less trivial to read (but there are ways around this if you mount a volume).
However, overall I found Docker much easier to use. I migrated away from using systemd to Docker in a much shorter period of time than it took me to initially setup my applications to run using systemd. It was a much easier system to use, despite the fact I am already somewhat familiar with systemd, and knew very little about Docker.
I would have liked to add this as an answer, but I cannot as the question is closed.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212438/how-to-stop-all-units-belonging-to-the-same-target

Here is an example showing how to use PartOf to make this work as intended.
[Unit]
Description=my description
After=network.target
PartOf=my_target.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=60
User=theuser
Group=thegroup
EnvironmentFile=/etc/example_env
WorkingDirectory=/var/log/example
StandardOutput=append:/var/log/example/service1.log
StandardError=append:/var/log/example/service1.error.log
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/example/.venv/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/example/service1.py
ExecStop=/bin/kill -TERM $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=my_target.target

